# How to solve this inner product ODE?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\boldsymbol{x}(t)$ be a vector and $\boldsymbol{A}$ be a matrix. I would like to solve
$$(\partial_t\boldsymbol{x})^\dagger A^\dagger A\partial_t \boldsymbol{x}=y$$
where $y \in \mathbb{R}_+$ and $\dagger$ donotes conjugate transpose, such that we obtain an expression $t=F(\boldsymbol{x}).$ The ODE can be easily solved under the special case
$$\partial_t x^* \boldsymbol{a}^\dagger \boldsymbol{a} \partial_t x=y$$
where $x$ is a scalar and $\boldsymbol{a}$ is a column vector (such that $\boldsymbol{a}^\dagger \boldsymbol{a}$ is also a scaler).

Any insights and comments are much appreciated.

Comment: Is $A$ a constant?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes, it is a constant.

Comment: In that case, this is equivalent to $[\partial_t(A\mathbf{x})^\dagger][\partial_t(A\mathbf{x})] = y$, right? So you can split this into two problems: solving $[\partial_t\mathbf{z}]^\dagger[\partial_t \mathbf{z}] = y$ and $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{z}$. Although I suppose this could run into issues if $\mathbf{z}$ is lower dimension than $\mathbf{x}$

Comment: Several things are unclear here. Firstly why the partials w.r.t. t? Secondly if $a^\dagger a$ is really just a scalar then why don't you just write it as c for some constant c? Why the need for writing it as an inner product? In fact you can just dispense with this constant altogether and absorb it into the right hand side $y$. Also $A^\dagger A$ is hermitian and hence diagonalizable, this might help you solve the problem.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Thank you very much. I think I have had some idea how to solve it under the case that A is a constant. But how about A itself is also a function of x? It seems that we can no longer absorb it into the derivative of t.

Comment: @user292458 A as a function of x makes this more nonlinear than it already is, and greatly decreases the likelihood of getting a solution. A as a function of t is more likely to produce something interesting.

Comment: @Leonid Thank you for your insights. Sorry for the partial derivative which is not a rigorous enough notation. Regarding the $a^\dagger a$, I wrote it out explicitly such that readers can easily see the connections between the two cases.

Comment: The diagonalization method for the constant case can reduce the equation to one of the form $\sum_{i = 1}^n |\partial_t z_i|^2 = y$. Which is still nonlinear, but seems like the kind of thing that has been studied.